# On an example of a discountinuous function in $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis

I write up a memory of mine that I am unsure is mathematically correct, my question will be to ask if it is correct.

In class we where observing that partial derivatives are not very satisfactory when giving information on the continuity of a multi-variable function. (A function can be discontinuous in a point but have both partial derivatives).

As an example we took the function defined as $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$ when $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and $f(0,0) = 0$.

And we noted that the partial derivatives in $(0,0)$ are both zero, while the function is not continuous in $(0,0)$ because fixing $y = x$ we obtain:

$$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{y^2}{2 y^2} = \frac{1}{y^2}$$ and this goes to minus infinity, so not to the value of the function that is zero.

My question is: is what I have written right? Please add something if you wish.

Comment: $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{y^2}{2 y^2} = \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fix $x=y$, you get $f(y,y) = \frac 1 2 $. If you fix $x = -y$, you get $f(-y,y) = \frac {-1}{2}$.

Therefore the function is not continuous at zero, since approaching zero from two different directions ($x=y$ and $x=-y$) yield different limits.